# Coefficients reported with restricted-cubic-splines in R package rms

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to understand some of the output of the package `rms` in R where I am using restricted cubic splines in quantile regression. The problem I have in understanding the output probably has more to to with restricted-cubic-splines generally than with the fact that I'm using them in quantile regression. I fit a restricted cubic spline function with *k*=3 knots as follows:

```
fitted.model <- Rq(y ~ rcs(x, 3), x=TRUE, y=TRUE, tau=0.50, data=d)
```

I am confused by the fact that

`coef(fitted.model)`

shows:

```
  Intercept        x       x' 

39.67901296  0.31760226  0.01875437
```

whereas

`Function(fitted.model)`

shows:

```
function(x = 56.15) {39.679013+0.31760226* x+1.2554621e-05*pmax(x-38.45,0)^3-2.3161627e-05*pmax(x-56.15,0)^3+1.0607006e-05*pmax(x-77.1,0)^3 }
```

Given formulas 2.24 and 2.25 in the RMS book, I anticipated that coefficients β<sub>0</sub>, β<sub>1</sub> and β<sub>2</sub> (i.e. β<sub>k-1</sub>) as obtained `coef(fitted.model)` would be the first three (i.e., k-1) coefficients shown with `Formula(fitted.model)`. The intercept (β<sub>0</sub>) and the coefficient for X (β<sub>1</sub>) are clearly the same, but β<sub>2</sub> shown in the formula is not the same as the second coefficient from `coef(fitted.model)`. What have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 5):

The coefficients reported from `Function` and `coef` differ from one another because of normalization. I was not able to find any description of the need for normalization (or its benefits and disadvantages) in the Regression Modeling Strategies book, which is what I had been reading. However, normalization is briefly described in the documentation for the function called `rcspline.eval` in Frank Harrell's `Hmisc` package where the `norm` argument is explained as follows:

> norm: 0 to use the terms as originally given by Devlin and Weeks
>   (1986), 1 to normalize non-linear terms by the cube of the spacing
>   between the last two knots, 2 to normalize by the square of the
>   spacing between the first and last knots (the default). norm=2 has the
>   advantage of making all non-linear terms be on the x-scale.

Hence, in the example I used in my question, the two coefficients *1.2554621×10<sup>-5</sup>* and *0.01875437* are related by the multiplicative factor *(77.1-38.45)<sup>2</sup> = 38.65<sup>2</sup> = 1493.82*, i.e., the square of the difference between the first and last knots in the example.

The ultimate effect of normalisation is to change the regression β weights, for the constructed spline variables but not for the intercept or unchanged x variable, by the normalisation factor. As Harrell explains, it makes the weights (coefficients) more interpretable in terms of the scale of x.